# RabbitMQ - high availability queues - but w/o messages replication

Tags: rabbitmq

I want to configure a RabbitMQ cluster between two nodes and I'm aiming for the active/passive approach in a way that if the master RabbitMQ is down for a reason I will route all traffic to the passive RabbitMQ ( via Haproxy or something ).

Basically I don't want to **replicate the messages to the passive brocker**, I need only the metadata ( queues/exchanges/bindings ), 
Does someone know if there is a way to sync only the metadata between the two rabbits ( w/o the messages ) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you have a cluster, everything except queues and messages are mirrored on all nodes. If you want to create queues on all nodes but you don't want the messages to be copied to all nodes, you have to make your app(s) create your queues on all nodes (or you have to do it via the command line/management UI).